# Is there a way to access location history data from an android app?

Tags: android, location

Ours is a financial app and to curb forgeries we wanted to access users location history from our android app.

The purpose behind this is if the user is requesting the service from a place where he hasn't been often or never been there, we would flag them or ignore them or implement another layer of security.

I have searched and found that google maps maintains location history and google plus may have an undocumented API also.

Please suggest how to get access to location history of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible unless you keep track of the location history yourself.